# chrome extension refresh two tab simultaneously

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I should write a chrome extension than can refresh two special tabs simultaneously when I click the extension icon. but I just find the code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab))
```

the `function(tab)` can not push two tabs but only one. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to refresh a `tab`, you only need `tab id`.So, you can use `chrome.tabs.reload()` on any number of tabs you like.

**Example:**

```
     chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
           chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true},function(tabs){// This will return all tabs in current window
           //If you want to reload first 2 tabs 
            chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[0].id);
            chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[1].id);
    })
 })
```

Lets say if you want to reload current `active tab` and the `tab` left to it. Then pass `active:true` along with `currentWindow:true` to get active tab. Then use index property to reload left or right tab.

**Example:**

```
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
           chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow: true},function(tabs){
            var currentIndex = tabs[0].index;
            var leftIndex = tabs[0].index - 1; 
             chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true},function(tabs){// This will return all tabs in current window
             chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[currentIndex].id);
             chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[leftIndex].id);
       });
    })
 })
```